# Bringing new 12/2 circuit to old knob/tube switches, but do not see a neutrals anywhere. Hidden?

Tags: electrical

I finally have an opportunity to complete 2 new 12/2 circuits (from one 12/3 on opposite phase breakers)  an electrician left when when the permit was closed after new service and substantial-but-not-complete update was done in 2004.

I have an opportunity to de-energize an old knob and tube branch the electrician left wired to a (different) new circuit, and dedicate a 20-amp circuit to bathroom lights/fan and another receptacle, although the bath already has a separate, dedicated 20-amp GFCI outlet.

But I got confused, because at old K and T switches I keep seeing only one hot power feed going into the box and only one wire for each fixture/or fan going out. (single power feed to switch with separate fan/light wires switched together shown here) They worked but I was unclear where the neutrals were (in the ceiling?) or how I could get it to work with the new 12/2 power feed. I did not want to rip up even more walls/ceiling than I have already if there is no need - so was going to keep the legs from switch to fixture if I could. Maybe that is a bad idea. Who can tell me what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Probably a shared neutral which was common with K&T.  Like you said, there could be one neutral in the attic, and you only see hot wires being switched.  The fixtures will all be connected into the shared neutral.  You might be able to see this in your new panel, because your neutral bus will have fewer conductors than there are circuits!  You'll could also notice if you shut off your breaker to the circuit you think you are working on, the neutral will still have current running through it when someone turns on a light switch that is on a different Knob and Tube branch! Ouch!

If this is the case, you should just rip it all out and do it right if at all possible.  Especially for bathroom you need to run have GFCI on all your circuits to be up to code and to be safe.

Comment: Thanks, house was built in 1950 with addition in 1960. I had not considered neutrals being shared across circuits at the fixture level. I will now. The 20 amp circuit I can make available is split from 240V  12/3 taking up 2 opposite phase 20 amp breakers. The neutral is shared with the other new circuit from that split. I suspect that would not be compatible with GFCI (?) There is one 20 amp GFCI circuit dedicated to a single outlet near the sink already, but I was hoping to have another outlet on circuit with lights/fan.

Comment: Only the receptacles require GFCI protection the lights and fan do not require GFCI protection. The wiring sounds like s standard switch leg, hot and neutral in the ceiling, hot goes to the switch and switched hot returns to the light.